# Pair Random Text With Random Image Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, random

I have a random image array, which displays images on my website with a different image displayed with each page refresh. It works just fine, thusly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_images = 5;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
var random_img = new Array();
random_img[0] = '<img src="img/picture1.png">';
random_img[1] = '<img src="img/picture2.png">';
random_img[2] = '<img src="img/picture3.png">';
document.write(random_img[random_number]);
</script>
```

What I would also like to do, directly below this image array, a standard HTML paragraph, is present a body of text which is paired with the image displayed.

So, if the random image array called up 'picture2', I would like to display 'text2' in a paragraph below it. 'picture1' would display 'text1', and so on.

Could anybody help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing the last bit of your question.

Comment: Sorry I hit 'post' before I was ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, your img tags need to be closed, I have corrected below also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var total_images = 5;
   var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
   var random_img = new Array();
   var random_text = [];

   random_img[0] = '<img src="img/picture1.png" />';
   random_text[0] = 'text1';
   random_img[1] = '<img src="img/picture2.png" />';
   random_text[1] = 'text2';
   random_img[2] = '<img src="img/picture3.png" />';
   random_text[2] = 'text3';
   document.write(random_img[random_number] + ' <br/><p>' + random_text[random_number] + '</p>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A quick additional question - what is the best way to style that text to suit the text on the rest of the page? (done in CSS?) Should I create a div around the script and style it that way?

Comment: Oh I see - I can do it within the script, between the '...' after the random_text callup.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got your answer, but here's another way of storing the information for access using an array of objects:

```
var arr = [
  { url: 'http://dummyimage.com/10x10/000/fff', text: 'text1' },
  { url: 'http://dummyimage.com/30x30/000/fff', text: 'text2' },
  { url: 'http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff', text: 'text3' }
];
```

Then you can then access the information using `arr[index].url` and `arr[index].text`.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/f9qJx/17/).